# Making polygons out of X,Y-point groups?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon-creation

I have `(X,Y)`-coordinates for different places in a single file. How can I make polygons from a group of points separated by `NULL`? A common method `'Points to line'` does not seem to work.

[image: xy cordinate with space with each different place]

For instance, from the picture above the first six points (`"SN"` from 1 to 6) will form the first polygon, next four points (`"SN"` from 8 to 11) will form the second polygon and so on.

Comment: PointsToLine requires a field on which to combine vertices. The dataset you present would be much more efficiently processed directly to polygons via a pair of cursors (search and insert).

Answer (score 2):

In absence of line ID we cannot make lines, but we can create their segments, dissolve them to lines, extract vertices and close line by using points to line tool.

The only tricky part is point one in above workflow. In order to create segment it's enough to shift table 1 record up and join it to original, easy to do in Excel. If you'd like to do in in ArcGIS, bring table to database and populate new field by using field calculator

```
[OBJECTID]-1
```

[image]

Use "Join field" tool to join original to itself using pair [objectid]<=>[shift]:
[image]

Select records without Null values and convert to segments by using it as input to XY to line tool. Dissolve output etc.:

[image]

Should work unless your lines are self-intersecting.